# Eclipse Java 'Expressions' window unable to evaluate Expression

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Using Eclipse Mars.1 and Java SE 1.8, the debugger is unable to evaluate expressions in the Expressions window.

The bug occurs when I run this line of code (the current program location is shown in red):

[image]

Immediately after I execute the line of code, the debugger Expressions window goes wrong:

[image]

I tried recreating my Workspace from scratch, cleaning up the projects... all to no avail.

I did check stackoverflow for possible explanations, but the postings I find are not directly related to my problem, which looks like a bug to me.

Thanks,

M

Comment: What do you variables say, 3 tab? (you should find the camera also here...

Comment: You should use hand drawn circles.

Comment: The 'variables' pane works fine. I do see the 'camera' variable, and it evaluates fine. Hovering over 'camera' also works fine.

Comment: Well, it's a bug. Cleaning, closing & opening all projects, closing & opening eclipse, etc. might fix it, or might not. We can't really help you here.

Comment: Bug filed. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=483297